# TypeScript: how can generate constructor function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor

I want to make correct constructor function on TypeScript, but I have problem. I've tried a lot of options, but the result is still no :(

My last version TS code: [open Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0A(()%3Avoid%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09function%20UserModule(arg1%3Aany%2C%20arg2%3Aany%2C%20arg3%3Aany)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20UserModule%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20arg1%20%3D%20arg1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20arg2%20%3D%20arg2%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20arg3%20%3D%20arg3%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20section%3Aany%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%20(section%3Aany%2C%20where%3A%20any)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.section%20%3D%20section%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%09this.getElem(%27%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getElem(new_elem%3Aany)%3Aany%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.section%20%2B%20this.arg1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D)()%3B%0D%0A)

Typescript appends to my code excess function:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Wyp.png)

See generated code:

```
(function () {
    function UserModule(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        var UserModule = (function () {
            function UserModule(section, where) {
                this.arg1 = arg1;
                this.arg2 = arg2;
                this.arg3 = arg3;
                this.section = section;
                this.getElem('');
                return this;
            }
            UserModule.prototype.getElem = function (new_elem) {
                this.section + this.arg1;
                return this;
            };
            return UserModule;
        }());
    }
})();
```

I want code:

```
(function () {
    function UserModule(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
            function UserModule(section, where) {
                this.arg1 = arg1;
                this.arg2 = arg2;
                this.arg3 = arg3;
                this.section = section;
                this.getElem('');
                return this;
            }
            UserModule.prototype.getElem = function (new_elem) {
                this.section + this.arg1;
                return this;
            };
            return UserModule;
    }
})();
```

Please help me remove this function. Thanks all!

Comment: Are you sure you're using TypeScript and not Vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: That's how typescript creates classes, the part you want to remove isn't removable if you want to use typescript classes. Why are you wrapping the class in a `UserModule` function? What are you trying to do? Also, please update your question with the typescript code.

Comment: Three `UserModule` functions? That's two too many.

Comment: @Mango, thanks you for answer. Yes, absolutely :)

Comment: @NitzanTomer, thanks you for answer. I want to use class as constructor in angular. I create service from function (arg1, arg2, arg3 - is DI for this service). I want to use class as constructor in my app, for example: new UserModule('section name', 'where value').getElem();

Comment: @Bergi, thanks you for answer. No, two functions is ok, one for implementation in Angular, second for using as constructor.

Comment: I don't see any angular code in your question? Did you mean to remove that IIFE and pass the outer function into Angular's module system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to alter the compiled JavaScript files. The 'excess' functions is there to implement `class UserModule` for you in JavaScript.

#### Update:

It look like you want to create different instances of your service. Implementing angular factories in TypeScript is fairly straightforward, by simply defining your service class locally in the service provider function.

See the implementation below:

```
interface IUserModelService {
    getElement: (param: string) => string;
}

function UserModelServiceProvider(
    $scope: ng.IScope,
    $http: ng.IHttpService
) {
    class UserModelService implements IUserModelService {
        constructor(
            private selection: string,
            private where: string
        ) { }
        public getElement(param: string) {
            return param + this.selection + this.where;
        }
    }
    return (selection: string, where: string) => {
        return new UserModelService(selection, where);
    };
}

yourAngularApp.factory("userModel", UserModelServiceProvider);
```

You can then inject this "userModel" into your controller, and use it to create your service instances.

Comment: thanks you, for your answer. But it not solved my problem.
I write it function for implement it in angularJS. I create a service, and arg1, arg2, arg3 - is DI for this service ($scope, $http for example). And I want use this service as constructor. For example: new UserModule('section name', 'where').getElem();

Comment: Angular Service cannot be instantiated like that. What you need is the angular factory.

Comment: In the official guide of AngularJS: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services have example: https://jsfiddle.net/n7fax62L/
It is created a service as constructor. 
When accessing the service from the controller, in the example not set all dependencies of service, only value of 'msg':
$scope.callNotify = function(msg) {
     notify(msg);
   };

In the typescript this impossible?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I need!